# Getting nova:628:die trying to start OpenStack nova module

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, openstack

Using devstack I am getting the following error when I run ./stack.sh

```
echo 'Waiting for nova-api to start...'
Waiting for nova-api to start...
+ wait_for_service 60 http://10.0.2.15:8774
+ local timeout=60
+ local url=http://10.0.2.15:8774
+ timeout 60 sh -c 'while ! curl --noproxy '\''*'\'' -s http://10.0.2.15:8774 >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done'
+ die 628 'nova-api did not start'
+ local exitcode=0
+ set +o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:1084:start_nova_api
/home/vagrant/devstack/lib/nova:628:die
[ERROR] /home/vagrant/devstack/lib/nova:628 nova-api did not start
```

The ip 10.0.2.15 is in the noproxy and I can ping it correctly

Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching I found the reason about this problem, and it was because in the directory /etc/nova there were two files with the owner=nova, and aparently this user is created automatically by devstack.

The solution was to change the owner of these files to my user.